# electron nodejs with c++ class in backend

Tags: javascript, c++, node.js, html, electron

I am fairly new to web development other than basic HTML5 website creation, I somehow understand the general structure but I still cannot understand fully especially electron and nodejs.

The other day I was going to create a webapp, which is similar to wysiwyg text editor but talks in between the browser (HTML5/js) with the backend (c++ script). 
What I first tried, was to have a c++ hello world script, which can be executed from the webapp built upon electron. I was able to run .exe as child_process but I couldn't get to further.

Now, I took myself a bit deeper research for looking into c/c++ addon from nodejs but still trying to understand. The basic examples on the nodejs doesn't seem to give me a full understanding on how to transfer data.

I'm sorry for the long paragraph to describe my status but in short, here are some questions:

1. Can anyone give me an idea of how Electron/nodejs can be used as a browser-backend middle interface?
2. Does anyone have a simple example / phedo-code with a propoer API use to talk in between nodejs-c++backend? Is nodejs c/c++ addon the only method ?

Thank you for reading! and I'll look forward anyone to help me understand.

Answer (score 0):

As you already figured out, Node.js offers the functionality you seek via its C/C++ Addons. Are you able to repoduce the basic callback example found [at the Node.js API manual](https://nodejs.org/api/addons.html#addons_callbacks)?

Answer (score 0):

In a different approach, [SWIG](https://www.swig.org/) is a software which interfaces C/C++ to other higher level languages like javeascript (nodejs).

A starter app [exists](https://github.com/flatmax/swig-Cplusplus-nodejs) which does this using C++ and SWIG. Let me break it down for you a little. You can take some C++ code :

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
  Test test; // test the construction and destruction of the Test class.
  return 0;
}
```

Then compile the [SWIG wrapper](https://github.com/flatmax/swig-Cplusplus-nodejs/blob/master/swig/swigCNodejs.i) to run the C++ code directly from nodejs :

```
var libSwigCNodejs = require('../swig/.libs/libSwigCNodejs');
let test = new libSwigCNodejs.Test;
```

If you want to take this over a network to the browser and have the browser directly execute the C++ code through nodejs, then it is a little more complex, however [this application](https://github.com/flatmax/lit-jrpc-swig) demonstrates how to do this using webcomponents, JRPC, nodejs, SWIG and C++.

In this case, you will use JRPC to abstract your class over the network to the browser, starting in nodejs like this :

```
const TestClass = require('./TestClass').TestClass;
let tc=new TestClass; // this class will be used over js-JRPC
// start the server and add the class.
var JrpcServer=new JRPCTools.JRPCServer(9000); // start a server on port 9000
JrpcServer.addClass(tc); // setup the class for remote use over the network
```

In the browser you will want to inherit JRPC-OO and use that class to operate the C++ class ([shown here](https://github.com/flatmax/lit-jrpc-swig/blob/master/src/LitJRPC.js)), with this type of inheritance :

```
class TestClass extends JRPCClient {};
```