# Stream OpenCV frames to Electron

Tags: opencv, electron

I'm trying to stitch videos coming from 2 cameras and stream the output to an electron application but I'm not really sure how to go about doing this.

Comment: What have you considered so far? You mention using OpenCV, have you researched any libraries?

Comment: I've tried piping the frames out to an rtmp stream using ffmpeg but I'm not sure how I can embed that into the electron app.

Comment: Have you begun developing the electron application yet?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37908639/electron-nodejs-with-c-class-in-backend